# ITeF!x Rsync with user authorization on Windows

Tags: windows, rsync

I'm trying to setup a Rsync server with user authorization on Windows. I'm not sure that it's possible, because of the lack of documentation. 
Has anyone suceeded in doing that with IteF!x Rsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to setup a ITef!x Rsync Server with user authorization on Windows. A example
module configuration would be:

```
[test]

path = /cygdrive/C/Test
comment = Test module for user authorization
read only = false
auth users = john
secrets file = /cygdrive/c/rsync.secrets
    GID=0
    UID=0
```

The "secrets file" must contain one line like this:

```
john:foo
```

Where "foo" is the password for user "john".
Then to access the module a command like this will work:

```
rsync.exe -v /cygdrive/c/testfile.txt john@rsyncserver::test
```